# Is there any protocol like UPnP for router Loopback? (Loopback NAT)

Tags: protocols, upnp, nat-traversal

We can use UPnP protocols to Forward users port. SO TO DO SIMPLE NAT TRAVERSAL. 
But problems appear after such operation.

My main point is - you can forward users port - bind it to globall adress, you can acsess it from glogal internet, but you can not from local network (ower the NAT). So I wonder if there is some protocol set that allow us sending soap requests (folowing that protocol like we follow UPnP to create nat traversal libs) configure NAT programmatically so that there would be proper Loopback for local net users.

I described [this - my detailed story on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/155125/why-proxy-servers-can-access-to-my-server-while-i-can-not) because some guys closed that question on stack. Back then it was not so detailed so I do not blaim tham (nat wary much)...

Answer (score 0):

You need a NAT router that properly supports hairpinned port redirections, c.f. [RFC 5382](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5382), section 7.2.  If your NAT router doesn't conform to those practices, then get one that does.